# In retrofit, can I get the endpoint uri with all dynamic values/query params before making the call?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

Following is my RetrofitApi interface

```
 const val USER_DETAIL = "private/{${Params.USER_NAME}}/details"

 @GET(USER_DETAIL)
 suspend fun getUsers(@Path(NetworkConstants.Params.USER_NAME) userName: String, @Query(NetworkConstants.Params.LANG) lang: String): Response<UserEntity?>
```

What I want is to know what is the URL after adding the query param and path to the respective url, like what is the final url **before** making API call.

Retrofit is making the final request url in its own library. How can i access that before making the request.

**Context:**

For caching purpose, I'm storing endpoints in db from the response interceptor. Now, before making another call, I want to check if that endpoint is already saved in my database or not. That's why I need to know what will be the final url.

Do I need to create my own Endpoint Builder Wrapper or does retrofit provides an easy way to access that final end point value?

Comment: You can intercept the request in same way . if i get your question correctly .

Comment: i want to check before the request. so that i should decide should i use the cached version or should i make a network call. using intercept means call is made. and if there is no internet connection interceptor won't be called.

Comment: For this you have build the URL before hand manually . Or you can cancel the request from interceptor(Check this one).

Comment: i tried with both addInterceptor and addNetworkInterceptor both of them are not being triggered when internet is not connected. And I need the endpoint even if I dont have internet. I guess I have to manually do this. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: if only there was a way where retrofit provided us to build the url before making the request... @jakewharton where are you

Comment: for future readers I added an issue here or future request: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3628

Comment: Call<ResponseBody> yourCall = api.getUsers(params, blah);

then before use use it with yourCall.enqueue you can check the url with yourCall.request().url()

Comment: you are right, that brings to another question when to use Call and when to use retrofit2.Response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to create wrapper class to build my end points, because retrofit doesn't expose url if you don't use retrofit CALL as return type.

I also created an issue/future request and Jake has responded: [github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3628](http://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3628)

Jake Wharton says:

> If you are using Retrofit's Call you can get the backing OkHttp
> Request which has the URL available. If you are using any of the adapters the URL is not exposed in any way.

Following is the calling code:

```
 val endPoint =  EndPointBuilder()
                        .setEndPoint(NetworkConstants.Url.USER_DETAIL)
                        .addParamsAndValue(NetworkConstants.Params.USER_NAME,"")
                        .addQueryParamAndValue(NetworkConstants.Params.LANG,"en")
                        .build()
```

Now the EndPointBuilder class:

```
//accommodate query and path params of retrofit
 class EndPointBuilder {

   private val pathParamMap = hashMapOf<String, String>()
   private val queryParamMap = hashMapOf<String, String>()
   private var endPoint : String? = null

    fun setEndPoint(endPoint: String): EndPointBuilder{
        this.endPoint = endPoint
        return this
     }

    fun addParamsAndValue(param: String, value: String): EndPointBuilder{
        pathParamMap[param] = value
        return this
     }
    fun addQueryParamAndValue(param: String, value: String): EndPointBuilder{
        queryParamMap[param] = value
        return this
     }

    fun build(): String{
        for((key, value) in pathParamMap){
            endPoint = endPoint.toString().replace("{$key}",value)
        }
        var queryString = ""

        var counter  = 0
        for((key, value) in queryParamMap){
            queryString = "$queryString$key=$value"
            counter++
            if(counter < queryParamMap.size){
                queryString= "$queryString&"
            }
        }

        endPoint = endPoint.toString() +"?"+ queryString
        return endPoint.toString()
    }
```

Here is my retrofit interface where url (without base url) is passed as an endpoint:

```
@GET
suspend fun getUsers(@Url url: String): Response<UserEntity?>
```